# Path Freely Homotopic To Conjugate Path

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f:I\to X$ and $\gamma:I\to X$ be loops in $X$.

The conjugate $\gamma^{-1}f\gamma$ is going to be freely homotopic to $f$ by some homotopy $H:X\times I\to X$, right? Can we choose it so that $H(x,-)$ is the path $\gamma$ for some $x$?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the base point, say $a$ in $X$ and that the loops are in $(X,a)$.  A usual picture for constructing a free homotopy $H$ $f \simeq \gamma^{-1}f \gamma$ is given by a retraction shown in the following picture

[image: retraction]

which is taken from [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html). The bottom edge of the square is mapped by  $f$ and the two vertical edges by $\gamma$.